# How to change UIButton image after a tap?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

The senario is I want to change a image of a button after I tap this button. I did like this:

```
func setImage(name: String, button: UIButton)
{
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: name) as UIImage?
    button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

}

@IBAction func ReadValueButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    setImage("ic_operation_start_indications_normal.png", button: sender)
}
```

This does not give any change at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace UIImage(contentsOfFile: name) as UIImage? by UIImage(named : name) as UIImage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a complete path with the `UIImage contentsOfFile` initializer. Use the `imageNamed:` initializer if you just have a file name for an image in your resource bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
```

instead of

```
UIImage(contentOfFile: "a.jpg")
```

Comment: 1) This gets, not sets, the image. 2) This answer is for the background image but the question isn't about the background image.